# Get type of payment for paypal-checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-webhooks

I implemented Paypal-Checkout which works fine so far. My problem is that I don't know which type of payment was used: Was it a "pay now"-option or a "pay later"-option?

I know that for me as a dealer it doesn't matter, but the customers are confused, because what should I write on the invoice? When writing "Thanks for your payment via Paypal", people thinks that everything is done and they needn't to do anything more (which is not true for "pay-later"-schemes). When writing "Please follow the instructions given by Paypal to pay our invoice", people which already payed get confused.

So is there really no good choice here? What do you recommend? Is there any way to get to know what the user selected?

I implemented Paypal-Checkout with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal keeps funding source information private by design. You will not know whether the payer used a balance in their account, a credit card, a bank account, PayPal Credit, Pay Later (Pay in 4/Pay in 3), Venmo in the US, or any one of the other [local payment methods](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/payment-methods/) that might be presented (depending on the buyer's location)

All you will know is that you received a completed PayPal payment, and the email address of the sender. So the best thing to display in your system as the funding source is indeed something like:

"Paid with: **PayPal** (logo image) emailofpayer@domain.com"

That is what all normal ecommerce sites do.

---

With a current [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) integration, it is technically possible to log which button on your site was *clicked* before proceeding with the checkout. However, the button clicked within your site may not correspond to what was ultimately payed with in the later completed transaction (it may fall back to a different method if the first declined, for example, or the user may change their mind about using Pay Later and pay with PayPal instead, or whatever). So this is not what you are asking for.